# show $(x+1)^p = x^p$ + 1 (mod p)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

for integer number a,b and p $\neq$ 0 is a=b (mod p) $\Leftrightarrow$ a-b is by p divisible.

let f=$\sum \limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ , g=$\sum \limits_{i=0}^n b_ix^i$ be polynomial so that f=g (mod p) $\Leftrightarrow$ $a_i=b_i (mod p), 0\leq i \leq n$.

let p be a prime number.

1) show $(x+1)^p = x^p + 1$ (mod p)

2) let a=$\sum \limits_{i=0}^n a_ip^i$ , b=$\sum \limits_{i=0}^n b_ip^i$ with $0 \leq a_i , b_i\leq p-1$ for $0 \leq i \leq n$

show ${a \choose b}={a_0 \choose b_0} \dots {a_n \choose b_n}$

can i show 1) with induction ? and how can i show 2) ?

Comment: What is your question about this problem?

Comment: About 1) : how would you use induction, given that the stated property is true only for prime exponents?

Comment: oops sorry forgot it , it was a wrong idea. i was thinking to use $(x+y)^n = \sum_i=0^n {n \choose i}x^iy^{n-i}$ with y=1 .

Answer (score 3):

**Using Fermat's little theorem**

$(x+1)^p \equiv x+1 \mod p$

$x^p \equiv x \mod p$

Therefore $(x+1)^p \equiv x+1 \equiv x^p +1 \mod p$

---

**Using the binomial theorem**

We have that

$$(x+1)^p = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^{k}$$

All binomial coefficients other than the first and the last are divisible by $p$, thus

$$(x+1)^p = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^{k} \equiv x^p+1 \mod p$$

Comment: Fermat's little theorem tells you that the polynomials $(x+1)^p$ and $(x^p+1)$ are equal when *evaluated* at the points in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. It does not directly imply that the two polynomials are equal *as polynomials*.

Comment: this is a great proof.